# Excel: Multiple (sorted) result from VLookup formula on array value

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365, vlookup

I have a list of data with 2 columns, from the first column I have a unique list of colours. From this list I want all the numbers that match that particular colour, if I use the VLOOKUP formula I only get the first result from the list.
When I have all the numbers it would be great that the result could be sorted too.
[image: screenshot]

Formula in D2:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A24;A2:A24<>0))
```

Formula in E2 (and E3,E4,...)

```
=VLOOKUP(D2;$A2:$B$24;2;ONWAAR)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried FILTER, TEXTJOIN, UNIQUE, and SORT?

Comment: Try: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B24,A2:A24=D2)),1))` though it will not really match your current results. Not sure how you got those.

Comment: @JvdV thanks again for your input.
Your function is almost good, the only thing is that the "," is at the beginning of the result, for example red is ",14". I tried to add the "," at the end but it gives me then ",14,".
It couldn't be a problem, but the thing is that I have more than 2 digits in my task, so I can't substract them with something else.
Any idea ?

Comment: does adding `TRUE` make a difference? `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B24,A2:A24=D2)),1))`

Comment: @P.b no it just adds the word "true" to the list (at the beginning). In this particular case the result is: ",TRUE11"

Comment: Textjoin is not concatenate. Textjoin has 1: a separator, 2: skip empty values true/false, 3: values to join (divided by given separator).

Comment: I think I entered the formula as you asked for, no?